# Long inputs in Matlab HDL coder

Tags: matlab, input, hdl-coder

I am trying to program a module in Matlab that will be translated to Verilog. My module has a lot of inputs, so I want to group them into a unique string of bits so the module will have only one input. The problem is that this input will be very long, and Matlab gives me the error:

> The input type exceeds the maximum number of bits (128)

How can I avoid this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Instead of making one long integer type can you use an array of integers?

Comment: If you declare the input as an array the HDL coder will put one input for each element in the array. I have more than 100 so I want to avoid that....